# Which Python interpreter to use for GTK3+/PyGObject when using Mysys2

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject, msys2

I'm trying to use GTK3+ / PyGObject with Python3 in Windows, with a Python IDE.

I successfully installed GTK3+ and PyGObject using Msys2 as per the instructions here: https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#windows-getting-started

When I run and use Msys2 (C:\msys64\mingw32.exe), GTK3+ bindings work fine in Python3. However, I also want to use GTK3+ / PyGObject outside of Msys2, in my regular Windows-based Python IDE.

Outside of Msys2, Python doesn't recognize PyGObject or GTK3+.
Example: **import gi**
will say module not found.

How can I make Python3 be able to use PyGObject outside of Msys2?

**What I've tried:**

I've tried pointing the IDE's Python Interpreter to C:\msys64\usr\bin\python3.exe
but when I do that, even print("hello") doesn't show anything.

Also, if I run C:\msys64\usr\bin\python3.exe from the Windows command-prompt, **import gi** will say module not found. But when I run python3 from within Msys2, **import gi** works fine.

Which Python interpreter should my Python IDE point-to to use PyGObject in Windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the Python3 interpreter from this path:

> C:\msys64\usr\bin\Python3.exe

I set my Python IDE to use this interpreter instead:

> C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\Python3.exe

After setting the Python IDE to use that path as the Python interpreter, I was able to run **import gi** just fine and my Python script also ran fine.

**Conclusion:** the problem was that the Python IDE was pointing to the wrong Python interpreter path.

Comment: How?? The MSYS terminal is a Linux environment whose paths don't match at all the Windows system. There isn't even a /C/ or matching directory. There is a mingw/bin/python3.exe though.